# htaccess redirect based on extension but on one domain only

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have just installed a CMS and all of my page name file extensions have now changed to .php instead of .html. I am told that editing the .htaccess is the best way to achieve this, however, in order to do that I have to change that in the root of my hosting account and I have multiple domains in my account (hostgator) and I only want the rule to apply to one domain specifically - not all domains. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess files are per-directory settings. You are correct that if you place one in your root directory it will affect all your domains, but the root directory is not the only place a .htaccess file is allowed -- you may put them in your domain-specific folder if you'd like that set of rules to only apply to that domain.

> htaccess files affect the directory they are placed in and all sub-directories, that is an htaccess file located in your root directory (yoursite.com) would affect yoursite.com/content, yoursite.com/content/contents, etc. It is important to note that this can be prevented (if, for example, you did not want certain htaccess commands to affect a specific directory) by placing a new htaccess file within the directory you don't want affected with certain changes, and removing the specific command(s) from the new htaccess file that you do not want affecting this directory. In short, the nearest htaccess file to the current directory is treated as the htaccess file. If the nearest htaccess file is your global htaccess located in your root, then it affects every single directory in your entire site.

[source](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml)

Comment: Excellent thank you - good to know. So if I simply add the following it should redirect all .html to .php right? 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L,R]